# Why does body onload require htmlentities on nested json_encode'd array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, json

I read database records, and create one PHP array() for each database record, then store each of these arrays as an element of a top-level PHP array().  The top level array is thus an array of arrays, and the nested arrays each contain the fields of one database record.  Nothing special here.

I need to pass the nested array of database record arrays to two different javascript functions and so I use json_encode in PHP before passing the nested array:

CASE #1: the first pass of the nested json_encoded-d is to a Javascript **function doSomeStuff( theNestedJsonEncodedArray)** -- I used a hidden iframe technique to pass the nested array into javascript code (see below)

CASE #2: the other pass of the nested array is to my web page's **body onload=handleLoad( theNestedJsonEncodedArray )**

With Case #1, I do *not* need  to use **htmlentities( theNestedJsonEncodedArray )** in order for this json encoded array to be successfully used in my **doSomeStuff()** function.

With Case #2, the **body onload=handleLoad( )** function will NOT EVEN EXECUTE.   Unless I add an extra step.  The extra step is this:   after json_encode'ing the nested array, I have to call **htmlentities()** -- then and only then will my **body onload=handleLoad( )** behave correctly.

I 100% fail to understand this.  I do not understand why, in the case of my "PHP/iframe/javascript" scenario, json_encode() is sufficient to pass the nested array -- but my "body onload=handleLoad()** case, I need to use htmlentities() on the nested array, or the onload javascript function will not even execute.

Note here:  there is zero html in my database records.

***CASE #1 CODE -- uses a hidden iframe to pass javascript code to my web page:***

```
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 $theTopLevelArray= array();

 for($i = 0; $i < $numrows;  $i++)
 {
    $theRow = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $recordNum = $theRow[0];
    $lat = $theRow[1];
    $lng = $theRow[2];
    $city = $theRow[3];
    $state = $theRow[4];

       // EACH NESTED ARRAY IS A TOWN with City, State, Latitude, Longitude
    $nestedArray =  array( $lat, $lng, $i, $recordNum, $city, $state);
    $theTopLevelArray[] = $nestedArray;
 }

 $jsonArray = json_encode($theTopLevelArray);
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
 echo 'var parDoc = parent.document;' . "\n";
 $sendToWebpageStr =  "parent.doSomeStuff( $jsonArray );";
 echo $sendToWebpageStr;
 echo "\n".'</script>';

  // And in my web page's javascript code......
 function doSomeStuff( theNestedJsonArray ) 
 {      
      // Traverse the array of Towns and show their latitude and longitude
    for (var i = 0; i < theNestedJsonArray.length; i++)
    {
       var town = theNestedJsonArray[i];
       var lat = town[1];
       var long = town[2];

       alert("The lat, long are: " + lat + ", " + long);
        // ALL THIS WORKS FINE.
    }
 }
```

***CASE #2 CODE -- REQUIRES AN EXTRA STEP, A CALL TO htmlentities( )***

```
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 $theTopLevelArray= array();

 for($i = 0; $i < $numrows;  $i++)
 {
    $theRow = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $recordNum = $theRow[0];
    $lat = $theRow[1];
    $lng = $theRow[2];
    $city = $theRow[3];
    $state = $theRow[4];

       // EACH NESTED ARRAY IS A TOWN with City, State, Latitude, Longitude
    $nestedArray =  array( $lat, $lng, $i, $recordNum, $city, $state);
    $theTopLevelArray[] = $nestedArray;
 }

 $jsonArray = json_encode($theTopLevelArray);
 $readyNowArray = htmlentities( $jsonArray );


 // AND HERE'S THE 'body' ON MY PAGE:

 <body onload="handleLoad( <?php echo $readyNowArray ?> )">      


 // HERE IS handleLoad()

 function handleLoad( theNestedArray )
 {

     var town = theNestedArray[0];
     alert("bl.js, handleLoad(), town is: " + town);
     alert("bl.js, handleLoad(), town[0] is: " + town[0]);
     alert("bl.js, handleLoad(), town[1] is: " + town[1]);
 }
```

If I **do not** call html entities for CASE #2 -- the handleLoad() function does not even execute.

Is there some nuance here when echo'ing a PHP array in the **body onload** tag that is requiring the extra step of calling htmlentities() on the json array, while passing the json array directly into javascript from PHP code by way of an iframe is bypassing that somehow?

Comment: A hidden iframe? Where is the code of that?

Comment: @Bergi, it's just standard hidden iframe technique, if you search 'hidden iframe' on SO there are lots of examples, you basically post a form to a php file which then outputs dyamic code to a hidden iframe on the page in such a way that this code dynamically appears on the page.  At least that's one way.  I use both Ajax and hidden iframe which achieve dynamic page content.

Comment: Ah, hidden iframe as a replacement for ajax is old-fashioned but ok. I thought you'd use a hidden iframe as a replacement for the onload callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some nuance here when echo'ing a PHP array in the body onload
>   tag that is requiring the extra step of calling htmlentities() on the
>   json array

Yes. You're echoing into HTML, for which you of course need `htmlentities`. If you don't, any quotes from the JSON will end your HTML `onload` attribute value, and the resulting js is nothing but a syntax error.

> while passing the json array directly into javascript from PHP code
>   is bypassing that somehow?

Inside a `<script>`, nothing but `</script>` does need to be escaped.

Comment: The reason for the iframe in my code is the javascript is not needed consistently.   I suppose I could embed the javascript tags -- but in order for my php code to echo the dynamic javascript code I'm not sure how I would 'locate' the hard-coded script start and end tags in order to correctly echo the actual javascript that is (conditionally) echo'd from PHP.  Because the javascript code is only required sometimes (based on user interaction) I found it easier to iframe the javascript only when the need arose.  And by the way, thanks for the answer, I suspected that but wanted a pro to confirm.